# In React v6, how to check form is dirty before leaving page/route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want a prompt to appear at the moment of wanting to leave the page without having canceled or without having sent the changes

As of v6.0.0-beta - useBlocker and usePrompt were removed I want to know another way to do it.

This doesn't work anymore:

```
<Prompt
when={formik.dirty}
message="You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave?"
/>
```

Nor this:

```
useBlocker(
() => "Hello from useBlocker -- are you sure you want to leave?",
isBlocking);
```

Comment: What library are you using here? `useBlocker` and `usePrompt` are not part of the standard react or react-native packages.

Comment: im using react-router-dom